# How can I change the parent of a GameObject instantiated via PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Usually you would instantiate a clone of a prefab in a script using

```
var obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(....);
```

and than change it's parent using

```
var obj.transform.SetParent(...);
```

However I'm writing on a little editor script for instantiating prefabs over the menu entries that should keep their link to the prefab. I do it in a `static` class like:

```
public static class EditorMenu
{
    // This is a reference that I already have and is not null
    privtae static Transform exampleParent;

    [MenuItem("Example/Create Clone")]
    private static void CreateClone()
    {
        var prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Example/Path/myObject.prefab", typeof(GameObject));
        var obj = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab);

        obj.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

        Selection.activeGameObject = obj;
    }
}
```

I had to use

```
(GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab);
```

because `Instantiate()` doesn't keep the link to the prefab but creates a clone.

So the above code works great so far and the object is inserted to the scene as if I would drag and drop it.

Now I would like to change this newly instantiated objects parent to `parent` so I added the line

```
obj.transform.SetParent(exampleParent, true);
```

I also tried

```
obj.transform.parent = exampleParent;
```

But both throw an exception:

> Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption.
>   UnityEngine.Transform:SetParent(Transform)

`prefab` and thereby `obj` are the topmost `GameObject` of the prefab so I thought I am setting the parent of the whole instantiated object not any transform inside of the prefab hierachy.

**How can I change the parent of a `GameObject` instantiated via [`PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab.html)**?

---

**Update**

A workarround I just tried was to actually use `Instantiate` and do

```
var obj = Object.Instantiate(prefab, cancel.transform);

// remove the added "(clone)" suffix
obj.name = prefab.name;
obj.transform.SetParent(cancel.transform);
```

however as mentioned before this doesn't completely keep the prefb functionality intact .. so it only allows me to `Revert` but **not** to `Apply` changes. As workaround it might be good enough however since in my case I use it as a shortcut for instantiating a prefab which users are not really supposed to change later...

Comment: Are you sure that `Instantiate()` can be called only from a MonoBehaviour? This is a static call `GameObject.Instantiate()`.

Comment: @z3nth10n no I just updated that part ;) I actually tried it again but it is not the same as using `InstantiatePrefab` since `Instantiate` brakes the prefab functionality like `Apply` changes

Comment: I found the issue see [post below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203097/7111561) the error message is bad formulated and the actual issue lies in a code I didn't provide so I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I just found the issue:

I didn't add it since the error message was confusing/bad formulated.

I was using [`Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html) for checking if the `exampleParent` of type `SomeType` was in the scene.

Following Unity's example which **should exclude** prefabs I used

```
// Validation for the Menu item
[MenuItem("Example/Create Clone", true]
private bool TargetAvailable()
{
    foreach (var target in (SomeType[])Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(SomeType))
    { 
        if (target.hideFlags == HideFlags.NotEditable || target.hideFlags == HideFlags.HideAndDontSave)
            continue;

        if (!EditorUtility.IsPersistent(target.transform.root.gameObject))
            continue;

        exampleParent = target.transform;
        return true;
    }

    exampleParent = null;
    return false;
}
```

**But** this seems actually to be wrong and not working since it allways returned me the `SomeType` reference from the prefabs! (I already found it a bit strange that they do

```
!EditorUtility.IsPersistent(target.transform.root.gameObject))
    continue;
```

I'm not sure if that `!` maybe is a type in their example code?!

---

So the error which sounds like setting the parent was not allowed actually means and should say

> *setting the parent **to** a Transform which resides in a prefab is not allowed ...*

than I would have found the actual issue in the first place.

---

So again as a workaround until I can figure out that `FindObjectsOfTypeAll` thing I switched to `Object.FindObjectOfType` instead assuming my target will always be active in the scene. And using `SetParent` works now together with `PrefabUtitlity.InstantiatePrefab`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the parent of a GameObject instantiated via PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab?

This is right, but make sure **cancel** is also an **instantiated** object.

```
obj.transform.parent = cancel.transform;
```

Comment: As said already this is what I am doing but it throws `Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption. UnityEngine.Transform:SetParent(Transform)`

Comment: Which version of Unity you are using, and how do you get the **cancel** object?

Comment: 2017.4.18. But I found the issue. It actually **was** how I get that parent transform .. the error message was just really bad formulated. See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203097/7111561). Upvoted you anyway since basically you are kind of right ;)